# Bedroom Radiator not operating properly

Tags: radiator, nest, water-circulating-heating

We have two Nest thermostats installed over a month ago and I am not sure the issue was after or before the installation of Nest thermostat.

We have two zones of heating installed in our house. One is for ground floor zone to control kitchen and living area heating system (with radiators) and second one is 1st floor zone to control bedrooms heating system (with radiators).

Recently I found that the one of the bedroom radiator heating is controlled with ground floor thermostat zone instead of first floor thermostat. I am confused where the problem is - is it the issue with Nest installation engineer did or my new property initial plumber did the wrong connections.

Please suggest me whom I need to turn for help? My Nest engineers says it is issue with plumbing work but my builder says it is Nest engineer who did the wrong connections.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to your word it seem it's piping that has been connected to day-zone collector instead of night-zone connector: It's a wrong piping, not a nest issue. Suggest you to put a thermostatic valve on that radiator so that room can be kept at desired temperature (if day t.stat asks for heat). Or hire a plumber to re-do the connections for that radiator.

Can you post a picture of the 'collectors' -> those places where pipes from all the radiators go? And also picture of radiator valves so we can help.